# Fitting map canvas inside the area

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, google-visualization

I'm trying to add google Geochart map of Canada in a card but it's going out of the box, how can I fit it inside

I'm using bootstrap CDN in React.
[image]

Card HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-xl">
         <div class="card-body">
              <div class="chart-area"> 
                   <div id="visualization" >
                   </div>  
              </div>
         </div>
</div>
```

JS for visualisation:

```
 var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
        document.getElementById('visualization'));
    geochart.draw(data, opts);
    $(window).smartresize(function () {
        geochart.draw(data, opts);
    });
```

Comment: you should be able to set height and width to '100%' in the chart options to fit the chart to its container -- but it would be helpful to see the code --> js, html, and css

Comment: @WhiteHat I've added the code required.

Comment: in `opts`, try adding --> `height: '100%', width: '100%'`

Comment: Actually it's working some devices perfectly but on some devices it's still the same.